# Disable visually italicizing characters in \textit when using LaTeX-Suite

Tags: vim, vim-latex

I am using Vim + LaTeX-Suite plugin to write LaTeX source file. I noticed that LaTeX-Suite would automatically italicize characters in `\textit` (which made text inside almost illegible) and bold characters in `\textbf` (which bolded text inside).

[image: Text inside <code>\textit</code> get visually italicized]

[image: Text inside <code>\textbf</code> get visually bolded]

So is there a way to disable this behavior?

Comment: May be a workaround is to change the font.

Comment: @Manuel Thanks. But all default fonts that is available in Vim has "oblique" font style. Are you suggesting to install new fonts?

Comment: I mean, I use Menlo, and its italics are absolutely readable. I don't know how vim works, but I thought that you would have all the system fonts available.

Comment: @Manuel I've found alternative on Windows, Meslo LG. Thanks for information.

Comment: You don't need to use *the exact one* it was just a suggestion, that may be you should look for a new font :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can edit the `highlight` for `texItalStyle` and `texBoldStyle`. I prefer to simply clear them by doing:

```
hi clear texItalStyle
hi clear texBoldStyle
```

You can find the highlight group of the text under the cursor by running the  mapping provided [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Identify_the_syntax_highlighting_group_used_at_the_cursor).

Comment: Is there a way to make this permanent in the .vimrc file?

Comment: @nalyd88 yeah, just paste it there :)

Comment: For some reason that isn't working for me. The only way it removes the highlight is if I type into vim when the file is open.

Comment: Thanks for the info btw. This really helped me.

Comment: I think it was getting overwritten by the default tex syntax. Adding the commands you show to `~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim` worked.

Comment: I think autocmd can help you:

au FileType tex hi clear texItalStyle
au FileType tex hi clear texBoldStyle

Comment: For the ones that are coming to this question in 2020, `texItalStyle` has become `texStyleItal` (likewise for `texBoldStyle`).