# How to Disable visual Effect of \textit{} in latex-vim?

Tags: vim, vim-latex

[Disable visually italicizing characters in \textit when using LaTeX-Suite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173445/disable-visually-italicizing-characters-in-textit-when-using-latex-suite)

The answer in that question was slightly different from what I want.

What philix says can't been added into .vimrc (at least it didn't work here)

I'm wondering if there's a way to completely disable it from the startup of vim.